# ksh/bash Formatting Files through sed by cat file|sed command

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I am trying to change the colors of content of a file conditionally.
My file is:

```
A  B  C  D
Value  Value  Value  Value  
Value  Value  Value  Value  
Value  Value  Value  Value  
Value  Value  Value  Value
```

My command is `cat file4 | sed "s,.*,${esc}[33m&${esc}[0m,"`, whose logic I understand to be:

1. Cat the file then by sed command edit the contents color by using the ANSI color codes.

But when I run this file generated is not as per desired:

```
[33mA  B  C  D[0m
[33mValue  Value  Value  Value  [0m
[33mValue  Value  Value  Value  [0m
[33mValue  Value  Value  Value  [0m
[33mValue  Value  Value  Value  [0m
```

Desired Output:

- Field A should be red.
- Field C should be in blue.
- Field D should be yellow.
- Field B should be green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this is a `UUOC` (*useless use of cat*). There is no good eason to use `cat` here, `sed` is perfectly able to read files itself, and even if it wasn't, then redirecting standard input from the file would be equivalent to piping it.

```
esc=$(echo -e '\e')
sed "s,\(.*\)  \(.*\)  \(.*\)  \(.*\),$esc[31m\1  $esc[34m\2  $esc[33m\3  $esc[32m\4$esc[m," file4
```

This is assuming the two spaces between the fields as you originally specified although that seems to have gone in an edit; adjust accordingly.

I have no idea why you thought your original way (match all text on a line, wrap it between two escape codes (for yellow) would give you multiple colours.

Comment: please tell me how you managed the <space> logic here

Comment: it has bug that it is providing colors to 3 values in a fields only I wanted that for column A all values in a one color , for column B all columns in a one color and so on

Comment: It's always easier for such things to be e.g. tab separated. If you're sure the column values won't contain spaces then replace the `.*` with `[^ ]*`. Besides that the script works fine as long as the input has exactly 4 columns separated by precisely 2 spaces, with no trailing spaces.

Comment: Its working now :)